# how to set the divider orange color of an alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

My app has been applied to a uniform orange theme. Now I need to custom the theme of an alertdialog, apply orange color to its title and divider. I can change the title color but divider color. So is there any solutions for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to set `<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>` in your `styles.xml`.

Also check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)

Comment: is it compatible with pre Android 5 OS

Comment: `android:colorAccent` will only work on api 21.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
final int titleDividerId = getResources().getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android");
final View titleDivider = dialog.findViewById(titleDividerId);
if (titleDivider != null) {                            
    titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
}
```